# Price per request in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I'm looking for prices of additionnal API calls within Google Analytics.
In the developers console, I can enter my billing information, but before, I'd like to find a price table somewhere.
I know that the free quota is 50 000 requests per month, I know we can ask for an extension, but I need much more and I'm ready to pay. The only question is : what does it cost ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

That's 50,000 requests per **day**. If you need more, you can go Premium, but even if you do some limits will remain the same. Check their page on [Collection Limits and Quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/limits-quotas). Pricing probably varies on your needs and scopes.